# Why are my canvas rect locations incorrect in this downsampling experiment?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, graphics

I am trying to build an observable notebook that down-samples an input image to a user-defined number of cells. An example of the experiment can be seen here: https://observablehq.com/d/dc19b499ca269533

Unfortunately at a smaller of number of cells (see under 50x50) the rectangle location of the left most cells seems to be calculated incorrectly. It is drawing kind of a triangle shape artifact (see attached).

I'm wondering if this has to do with Javascript Floating Point rounding errors with multiplication and division) Or If I have some incorrect Logic somewhere.

[image: original image]
[image: downsampled image]

I've added the code in question below (using iife to match observable behavior), but to dig in you will want to visit the original notebook.

```
const data = (() => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    const columnWidth = img.naturalWidth / columns;
    const rowWidth = img.naturalHeight / rows;
    const getCellData = (rowIndex) => 
        [...Array(columns)]
        .map((_, columnIndex) => {
            const imgData = ctx.getImageData(
                columnIndex * columnWidth,
                rowIndex * rowWidth,
                columnWidth,
                rowWidth
             );
            // each chunk represents a color
            return lodash.chunk(imgData.data, 4);
        });


    return [...Array(rows)]
    .map((_, rowIndex) => getCellData(rowIndex));
});


const averagedData = (() => {
  const getCellAverage = (pixels) => pixels
    .reduce((
      [sumR, sumG, sumB, sumA],
      [r,g,b,a]
     ) => [
      sumR + r,
      sumG + g,
      sumB + b,
      sumA + a
     ] , [0,0,0,0])
     .map(v => v / pixels.length);


   return data.map(row => row.map(getCellAverage))
})()


(()=>{
  const columnWidth = img.naturalWidth / columns;
  const rowWidth = img.naturalHeight / rows;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

  averagedData
    .forEach((row, rowIndex) => row
      .forEach(([r,g,b,a], columnIndex) => {
        ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a})`;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(
          columnWidth * columnIndex,
          rowWidth * rowIndex,
          columnWidth, columnIndex
        );
        showBorder && ctx.strokeRect(
          columnWidth * columnIndex,
          rowWidth * rowIndex,
          columnWidth, columnIndex
        );    
     }))
})()
```

Comment: Why is your rectangle height the index in the array? `ctx.fillRect(
          columnWidth * columnIndex,
          rowWidth * rowIndex,
          columnWidth, columnIndex);`

Comment: @ASDFGerte thank you you solved it.